# Should I use lambda functions where a free function could have been used?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, namespaces, c++14

Imagine I have a .cpp file, which inside has some helper code. I can put that code inside some anonymous namespace. Are there disadvantages to use a lambda function for this? Example:

```
namespace {

auto to_string_lambda = [](int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return "zero";
  }
  else if (n == 1) {
    return "one";
  }

  return "unknown";
};

// VS:

auto to_string_func(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return "zero";
  }
  else if (n == 1) {
    return "one";
  }

  return "unknown";
};

} // anon ns
```

Comment: There's probably no direct disadvantage and the same code probably gets generated but why would you want to do this?

Comment: Do whichever you prefer and find easiest to read.  A named function is equivalent if there's no captures; a lambda is much more readable if you need to capture any values.  If it's only used once, I often find a named lambda to be effective, and it can be declared right where it's used.

Comment: thanks, I think I found another question which answers this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19919754/939050

Comment: That's a different question, putting them inside other functions hides them from the global scope, using lambdas as globals is just extra typing